# Use XSL to Iterate over Elements in For Each Loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

so I have been having serious issues getting this to work (and I'm sure it is simple, I have little experience with XSL).

I am trying to iterate over a bunch of very different child elements in an xml document that is structured like this:

```
<transaction>
 <data_xml>
  <document data_type="0">
   <element1>value1</element1>
   <element2>value2</element2>
   <element3>value3</element3>
  </document>
 </data_xml>
</transaction>
```

I am using XSL version 1.0, and I'm pretty sure that I cannot use 2.0 for this considering the constraints of the system I am working in.

The output I want is:

```
<foo>
 <bar:element1><!CDATA[[value]]></bar:element1>
 <bar:element2><!CDATA[[value]]></bar:element2>
 <bar:element3><!CDATA[[value]]></bar:element3>
</foo>
```

The awful hideous code I am currently using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <foo>
  <xsl:for-each select="/transaction/data_xml/document[@data_type='0']/*">
   &lt;bar:<xsl:value-of select="name(name(/transaction/data_xml/document[@data_type='0']/*)"/>>
   &#60;![CDATA[<xsl:value-of select="/transaction/data_xml/document[@data_type='0']/*"/>]]&gt;
   &#60;/bar:<xsl:value-of select="name(/transaction/data_xml/document[@data_type='0']/*)"/>>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </foo>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use this, though, it just iterates over the same element multiple times, instead of each element in turn.

Any ideas? Besides shooting me for terribad looking code?

Comment: Your requested output is not a well-formed XML document (the `bar:` prefix must be bound to a namespace). And why is the CDATA value identical in all three?

Comment: The XSL is also invalid according to my transformer.

Comment: Because I'm a dumb-dumb and I didn't double check things. Thank you for your comments though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:bar="http://example.com/bar">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <foo>
        <xsl:for-each select="transaction/data_xml/document[@data_type='0']/*">
            <xsl:element name="bar:{local-name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </foo>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which, applied to your example input, would result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns:bar="http://example.com/bar">
   <bar:element1>value1</bar:element1>
   <bar:element2>value2</bar:element2>
   <bar:element3>value3</bar:element3>
</foo>
```

If you want the various `bar:elementX` values to be CDATA sections, you should specify so in the `<xsl:output>` instruction so:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="bar:element1 bar:element2 bar:element3"/>
```

However this requires you to know all possible element names in advance. Otherwise you'd have to hack it, for example as:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <foo>
        <xsl:for-each select="transaction/data_xml/document[@data_type='0']/*">
            <xsl:element name="bar:{local-name()}">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </foo>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is a much better implementation that looks good AND makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- You can use `name()` or `local-name()` with no arguments to get the name of the current element.
- You should be using `xsl:element` to create elements with dynamic names. You shouldn't be manually building their tags:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:bar="namespaceForBarGoesHere"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <foo>
      <xsl:for-each select="/transaction/data_xml/document[@data_type='0']/*">
        <xsl:element name="bar:{local-name()}">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </foo>
 </xsl:template>
```

Produces this result:

```
<foo xmlns:bar="namespaceForBarGoesHere">
  <bar:element1><![CDATA[value1]]></bar:element1>
  <bar:element2><![CDATA[value2]]></bar:element2>
  <bar:element3><![CDATA[value3]]></bar:element3>
</foo>
```

Comment: I believe your CDATA simulation produces an incorrect result.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I was missing the exclamation point. Should work now.