# How can I iterate the following ArrayList of object using Apache Fop

Tags: java, xml, xslt, apache-fop

I have an Java object which contains primitive along with an list. The xml representation of the list is as below. How can I iterate the following xml structure using fop to get a tabular structure in pdf.

```
<customer>
    <group>
        <maxAge>100</maxAge>
        <minAge>200</minAge>
        <maxSalary>100</maxSalary>
        <minSalary>100</minSalary>
    </group>
    <group>
        <maxAge>200</maxAge>
        <minAge>200</minAge>
        <maxSalary>400</maxSalary>
        <minSalary>100</minSalary>
    </group>
    <group>
        <maxAge>300</maxAge>
        <minAge>300</minAge>
        <maxSalary>500</maxSalary>
        <minSalary>100</minSalary>
    </group>
</customer>
```

I have tried the following xml but it does not work. I just get a blank page in place of table, while the primitive data gets printed.

```
<fo:root>
             <fo:page-sequence>

            <!-- there is a sequence here this which binds primitive

             </fo:page-sequence>
        <xsl:for-each select="group">
          <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
            <fo:table-column/>
            <fo:table-column/>
            <fo:table-column/>
            <fo:table-column/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row background-color="lightgray">
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block font-size="12pt">
                                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block font-size="12pt">
                                <xsl:value-of select="maxAge"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block font-size="12pt">
                               <xsl:value-of select="minAge"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block font-size="12pt">
                                <xsl:value-of select="maxSalary"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block font-size="12pt">
                               <xsl:value-of select="minSalary"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:root>
```

Any link or suggestions? I have already looked up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199859/use-xsl-to-iterate-over-elements-in-for-each-loop) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455837/for-each-for-apache-fop) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863549/for-each-in-fop-xml) and many other links but I am still stuck at this.

Comment: Your code block seems to consist mainly of an unclosed comment? - Your `<xsl:for-each select="group"` could be meant to be `<xsl:for-each select="/customer/group">` ?

Comment: I am very new at this..I do not have much idea parsing xml either. Kindly suggest if you find any parsing error. However all the syntax and comments are well closed in code and it compiles fine...